# WooCommerce custom product status not visible / working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Because I needed to create a custom product status I've searched on google "WooCommerce create custom product status" but found no results. So I remembered that a product in WooCommerce is just like a post in WordPress so I've searched "Create custom post status in WordPress" and found a tutorial.

**I've did it like described there and this came out**

---

I've first registered a custom post status in my themes function.php:

```
register_post_status( 'custom-hide-product', array(
    'label'                     => _x( 'Produkt versteckt', 'post' ),
    'public'                    => false,
    'exclude_from_search'       => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Produkt versteckt <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Produkt versteckt <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
) );
```

After this I've done the second part from the tutorial to get the status into the dropdown:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'display_hide_status_option' );
function display_hide_status_option() {
    global $post;
    $complete = '';
    $label    = '';
    if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
        if ( $post->post_status === 'custom-hide-product' ) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        }
        echo '<script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"custom-hide-product\" ' . $complete . '>Produkt versteckt</option>");
                    $(".misc-pub-section label").append("' . $label . '");
                });
              </script>
        ';
    }
}
```

The dropdown in a product:

[image]

But when I check the product status dropdown my custom post status isn't visible / set or whatever. Can you see the problem? I cant..

Answer (score 0):

Your post type is incorrect. Your code creates a drop-down for generic Wordpress posts, but not products.

This line:

`if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {`

Should be:

`if ( $post->post_type === 'product' ) {`

Comment: By the way, unless you set `'public' => true` in your call to `register_post_status()`, any products set to your custom status will not be searchable even on the back-end, regardless of the value you set for `exclude_from_search`. They will also not appear under All Products.